# nsdictionary objectforkey - search and get that value

Tags: iphone, nsdictionary

I'm using NSDictionary in my iphone app.
I am using "objectForKey:" method to get the value of a key.
One thread (first thread) is adding key-value to a dictionary and other thread (second thread) is reading them.
In second thread, i want to get a value for a key which first thread some times didn't add by that time. So, in 2nd thread i want search for some key and then get that value. Possible?
What if I provide a key in dictionary that doesn't exist? what will it return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [NSLock](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSLock_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to synchronize access to your dictionary, in order for your operation to be threadsafe. As for your question about the [[NSDictionary -objectForKey]](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/objectForKey:) method, according to the documention, it will return `nil` if the key is not present (i.e. has no associated value) in the dictionary.